# angular without dependencies is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started angular js and l started with the basic declaration of a module without services and factories. It was working well before adding services and factories. Now after adding services and factories its not working anymore.

The first declaration that is not working anymore:

```js
angular.module('root',[])
.controller("index",["$scope",function ($scope){
    $scope.message="My name";
    $scope.favouriteWord;
    $scope.favouriteColor;
    $scope.favouriteShape;
    $scope.value = 1;
    $scope.isBold = function() {
        return ($scope.value % 2===0);
    }

    $scope.isUnderlined = function() { 
        return ($scope.value % 5===0);
    }

    $scope.products=[
              {id: 1, name:"House Jockey"},
              {id: 2, name:"Golf club"},
              {id: 3, name:"Baseball Bat"},
              {id: 4, name:"Lacrosse stick"}];
    $scope.favsha = true;
    $scope.factor = 6;
    $scope.product = $scope.factor * 2;
}]);
```

The factory added:

```js
angular.module('root',["services"])
.controller("index",["$scope","square",function ($scope,square){
    $scope.product=square;
}]);
```

The service added:

```js
angular.module('root',["services"])
.controller("index",["$scope","message",function ($scope,message){
       $scope.message=message;
}]);
```

Comment: what is `["services"]` dependency that you added to app?

Comment: Its a module called services

Comment: Where is it? Have you defined a module called "services"?

Comment: yes, in services.js and the service is working well, but after adding the service, my initial declaration is now working, that is the one without a module injected in it

Comment: Can you please share the error that you got?

Comment: What error are you getting while adding services and factory as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring the module 'root' instead of adding a new module 'services', since you´ve again added 'services' to your to the dependencies. You don´t have to redeclare 'root' in the new module, since it should be standalone and portable. Check out the module documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Your 'services' module should be declared like this:

```
angular.module('services'])
.controller("index",["$scope","message",function ($scope,message){
$scope.message=message;
}]);
```

Comment: I did mention that my service and factory re both working well, the only problem is the one without a service or factory

Comment: Sorry, i got that wrong. Can you please show the code of message and square?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an important part of angular.module function.

The function acts as a getter and a setter, depending on the arguments supplied.

`angular.module('module name', [...])`

Where [...] is the array of dependencies, is a "setter", so it will create a module.

Now, after it was created, to get the module and add controllers, services etc on it, omit the dependencies array.

`angular.module('module name')`

Also, you must define the `services` module before your `root` module.

```
// Define 'services' module
angular.module('services', []);

// Adds factory to 'services' module
angular.module('services').factory('factoryName', function() {
    // Implement factory...
});

// Define 'root' module
angular.module('root', ['services']);

// Adds controller to 'root' module
angular.module('root').controller('controllerName', ['$scope', 'factoryName', function($scope, factoryName) {
    // Implement controller...
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Services or Factories in angularJS can not be injected from module

```
angular.module('root',["services"])
```

the above one is wrong

services and factories are injected to the controller directly

```
angular.module('root',[])
.controller("index",["$scope","service",function ($scope,service){
```

if your issue is not resolved,please post service/factory code,may get more idea on problem.